# When does shouldInterceptRequest() is called in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am new to android so I'm little confused with the shouldInterceptRequest() method in android webview. When does this method is being called, is it after the request is being processed in the backend server or before the request is made to the backend server. A little detail will be appreciated,or any link to get the details of the matter.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldInterceptRequest()` is called before the request goes to the server. I'll see if we can clarify this in the API documentation, but this [integration test should serve as evidence](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/javatests/src/org/chromium/android_webview/test/AwContentsClientShouldInterceptRequestTest.java?l=621&rcl=14933aaa741c2c51a0521271a35358742b1198cb): the server never sees the request because the test injects its own response to the request.